# Change of Basis: finding $A$ for $T(x)=Ax$

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

So my basis is the column vectors of \begin{pmatrix}a&0&0\\ \:b&a&0\\ \:c&b&a\end{pmatrix}

I was taught the relationship $\text{A = Q$^{-1}$[T]$_\text B$Q}$ and I think $Q^{-1}$ should be equal to my basis and then $Q$ will be the inverse of that. How do I find $[\text T]_\text B$ if $T(x)=Ax$?

Comment: What you have described as a basis is not a basis in the usual sense of the term, so it is unclear what you are trying to say

Comment: Sorry. Does it help that x,y,z are not specific coordinates and are a basis for R3? Part a of the question had me find a basis for R3 and I just chose to use x,y,z, so they could be replaced by a,b,c if that's better

Comment: Could you type the exact text used for part a of the question?  The fact that you're calling your matrix "a basis of $\Bbb R^3$" makes this even more confusing

Comment: Consider A∈Mat3×3(R) and the vector v∈R3 such that (A^3)v= 0, but (A^2)v is not equal to 0
(a)  Show that the vectors A^2v, Av, and v form a basis of R3
Hint: It is sufficient to show they are linearly independent.  Set up the proper equation, and multiply by A^2
(b)  Find the matrix of the transformation T(x) =Ax with respect to the basis {A^2v,Av,v}

Comment: So I solved part a and got the column vectors above as a basis for R3

Comment: First of all, the fact that the columns of the matrix were meant to be the elements of you basis was not clear; thanks for clarifying that.  Remember that a basis, by definition, is a list of vectors. Now, why do you the column vectors you are using contain $a,b,c$?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry. Okay so in part a) I said that v was the vector (a,b,c) and then solved for A^2v and Av using A = {(010)(001)(000)}. So then I got the 3 column vectors

Comment: Okay, now things are getting much clearer.  How did you decide that 
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}?
$$

Comment: Oh A was \begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\ \:1&0&0\\ \:0&1&0\end{pmatrix} (sorry that's my bad on the formatting) because A^2 is not equal to 0 but A^3 is

Comment: But even if we know that $A^2 \neq 0$ and $A^3 = 0$, we don't have enough information to decide that 
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0}.
$$
For example, the "wrong" version of $A$ that you gave has exactly the same property

Comment: Ok. So I should be trying to find a general form for the matrices that follow these rules? I don't see how that would be possible.

Comment: Not quite.  In fact, we are supposed to go through the entire question without specifying the exact form of $A$.  I'll write something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in full (as discussed in the comments):

> Consider $A \in \mathrm{Mat}_{3 \times 3}(\Bbb R)$ and a vector $v \in \Bbb R^3$ such that $A^3 v = 0$ but $A^2 v \neq 0$.
>
> 1. Show that the vectors $A^2v$, $Av$, and $v$ form a basis of $\Bbb R^3$ Hint: It is sufficient to show they are linearly independent. Set up the proper equation, and multiply by $A^2$.
> 2. Find the matrix of the transformation $T(x) =Ax$ with respect to the basis $\{A^2v,Av,v\}$.

To answer question 1 (part a), recall the definition of linear independence.  If $c_1 A^2v + c_2 Av + c_3 v = 0$, then it is supposed to hold that $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are all necessarily zero.  So, suppose that $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are such that $c_1 A^2v + c_2 Av + c_3 v = 0$.  Note that
$$
c_1 A^2v + c_2 Av + c_3 v = 0 \implies \\
A(c_1 A^2v + c_2 Av + c_3 v) = A(0) \implies\\
c_2A^2 v + c_3 Av = 0  \implies\\
A(c_2A^2 v + c_3 Av) = A(0) \implies\\
c_3A^2 v = 0
$$
Now, by considering the first, third, and fifth lines above, conclude that $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are all necessarily zero.

To answer question 2 (part b), we can use the following procedure to find $[T]_{\mathcal B}$.  If $\mathcal B = \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ and $M = [T]_{\mathcal B}$, then the elements of the $j$th column of $M$ are the numbers $m_{1j},m_{2j},m_{3j}$ for which
$$
T(v_j) = m_{1j}v_1 + m_{2j}v_2 + m_{3j}v_3.
$$
So for example: to find the second column of $[T]_{\mathcal B}$ for our $T$ and $\mathcal B = \{A^2 v, Av, v\}$, note that
$$
T(Av) = A(Av) = A^2 v = 1 \cdot A^2 v + 0 \cdot Av + 0 \cdot v.
$$
So, the second column of our matrix is $(1,0,0)$. In other words, we have
$$
[T]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{?&1&?\\?&0&?\\?&0&?}.
$$

Comment: Thanks so much! This is really helpful :)